# Can I use Accordion in the Email template design with HTML and CSS only

Tags: html, css, windows, accordion, email-templates

I needed to know if I can use accordion in my HTML Email template design.
I know that HTML Email template has many restrictions to it and we can not use every CSS tricks even if we want.
I have an trying to add a simple accordion on my email template but it's not working when I tested on emails.
This code I found in 'code pen' and trying to test it on email on the acid account but it doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  background: #CCC;
}
main {
  background: #EEE;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  font-size: 13px;
}
input {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
label {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  color: #666;
}
label:hover {
  color: #000;
}
label::before {
  font-family: Consolas, monaco, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  content: "+";
  vertical-align: text-top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #CCC 50%, transparent 50%);
}
#expand {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/600/300);
  color: #FFF;
}
section {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
#toggle:checked ~ #expand {
  height: 250px;
}
#toggle:checked ~ label::before {
  content: "-";
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<main>
  <h2>CSS Expand/Collapse Section</h2>
  <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="toggle">Hidden Kitten</label>
  <div id="expand">
    <section>
      <p>mew</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <section>
    <h3>Other content</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas porta non turpis faucibus lobortis. Curabitur non eros rutrum, gravida felis non, luctus velit. Ut commodo congue velit feugiat lobortis. Etiam nec dolor quis nulla bibendum blandit vitae nec enim. Maecenas id dignissim erat. Aenean ac mi nec ante venenatis interdum quis vel lacus.
    </p>
    <p>Aliquam ligula est, aliquet et semper vitae, elementum eget dolor. In ut dui id leo tristique iaculis eget a dui. Vestibulum cursus, dolor sit amet lacinia feugiat, turpis odio auctor nisi, quis pretium dui elit at est. Pellentesque lacus risus, vulputate sed gravida eleifend, accumsan ac ante. Donec accumsan, augue eu congue condimentum, erat magna luctus diam, adipiscing bibendum sem sem non elit.</p>
  </section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me out if anybody out there has used accordion in their email templates and made it work. Thanks!

Comment: In the email template, pseudo class won't work, rest of your code is fine to use in the email template.

Comment: In which OS email app did you check the HTML content? In general, accordion will not work in Gmail.

Comment: @SatheeshKumar gmail now supports media queries, so accordions should work and there are ways to actually target Gmail only. There are ways to target most of the devices as well, its just a matter of testing.

Comment: Syfer , can you please give any links  which will show me how @media works in gmail? So far I had no luck with media queries in gmail

Comment: It's against the rules to do that. If you are using media queries I suggest updating your code to reflect that and update your question in the OP. If you do want to search (which I hope you will do) then look for litmus and campaign monitor blogs. They have a lot of resources for emails.

Answer (score 0):

Many email clients don't support pseudo-classes, therefore, you have to build your email template accordingly. Here's the [list](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/) of email client that supports pseudo classes

Comment: Here is another link you might want to reference. It is better than the mailchimp one and is more in-depth: [Campaign Monitor CSS guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-head/)